# The <kbd> markdown on StackExchange renders weird — needs a fix?

Tags: bug, design, css

[I had a question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39837/track-visitor-use-of-ctrl-f-on-a-website) here on Pro Webmasters StackExchange where I used the following markdown:

```
Would it theoretically be possible to detect (e.g. JS) 
if a user queries a webpage with the Windows shortcut 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, or the Mac-equivalent 
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in their browser?
```

It came out OK:

[image]

But further down, when I used the `<kbd>` code mid-sentence, it looks very odd due to the line-height:

[image]

Anything we can do to change this (e.g. CSS), or am I misusing it?

Would probably benefit the whole StackExchange network.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though this topic has come up at StackOverflow Meta:

> The "fix" would require line-height to be set to an absurd number, so
>   I don't think this will be "fixed".
>
> In general you should avoid two  elements near each other
>   vertically, just like you'd avoid making your entire post bold for
>   example.

Accepted answer from Jeff Atwood for [Overlap of `<kbd>` elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60980/overlap-of-kbd-elements)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that MSO post actually applies here -- that referred to `<kbd>` elements overlapping on consecutive lines. I'll look into this.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to make the actual elements smaller, instead of increasing the line-height.